# AWS signature version 2 using javascript

Tags: web-services, api, amazon-web-services, signature

I want to consume AWS product advertising API, I stuck with generating Signature.
Can someone please post the code snippet for creating signature using Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until last hour ago. After googling many links. Finally i found solution for it.
My solution is here

```js
var Message = "GET" + "\n" + "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com" +"\n"+ "AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Action=DescribeJobFlows&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30&Version=2009-03-31";

var secret = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(Message, secret);
document.write(hash);
document.write("|| and ||");
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
document.write(hashInBase64);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/enc-base64.js"></script>
```

You can verify your signature from https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html
But beaware of timestamp. Signature vary depends on timestamp

Comment: my pleasure :-)